# Custom Video Player in android with youtube streaming capabilities

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, exoplayer

I have extended exoPlayer and have successfully got content on my server run. but problem is i dont have any clue how to integrate youtube without using youtubePlayer. i cant use standalone youtube player because of legal issues.

I have went through youtube data api doc but found little help out there. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you running into errors with your ExoPlayer Implementation or elsewhere?

Comment: I dont have streaming url (HLS/dash) for the content i want to stream.

Comment: Similar question, though not the same exactly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620637/how-to-play-youtube-url-in-exo-player